# Python regex capture non-empty citations

Tags: python, regex

I would like to capture the text from articles in quotation marks `\"`. I name my capturing group `(?P<citation>)`. I exclude specific characters inside the citation using `[^\"\.\;]`.

```
\"(?P<citation>[^\"\.\;]+)\"
```

It works, but it also captures empty citations `" "` which is a space character between the end of a citation and the beginning of the next one. Is there a way to exclude that without affecting any other space characters ?

Comment: Prevent matching only whitespace chars till the first double quote `"(?P<citation>(?!\s+")[^".;]+)"` https://regex101.com/r/lJmwZp/1

Comment: It worked thank you ! I was trying a non capturing group `(?:\s)` but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negated character class `[^".;]+` matches any char except the listed, which can also be a whitespace char. *(Note athat you don't have to escape the characters in the character class)*

If you want to allow whitespace chars, but not only whitespace chars, you can use a negative lookahead `(?!\s+")` asserting that there are not only whitespace chars until the next double quote.

```
"(?P<citation>(?!\s+")[^".;]+)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJmwZp/1/)

Without using a lookahead, you can make sure to match at least a single char `[^\s".;]` except being one of the chars that you don't allow or matching a whitespace char between optional negated character classes.

```
"(?P<citation>[^".;]*[^\s".;][^".;]*)"
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gg5Gmk/1)